# Modify Bootstrap Collapsed Mobile Menu width. (not editing collapse breakpoint)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to modify the styling on the collapsible part of the Bootstrap menu so it does not stretch the entire width of the mobile screen. I would like to push it in 15px on each side, so when the `.navbar-toggle` button is tapped and the menu collapses out, you can see the background too. I have tried this:

```
.navbar-collapse {
   padding-right: -15px;
   padding-left: -15px;
}
```

However this did not work. I have put some Photoshop mockups below to help explain what I need to achieve, here is the markup:

```
<div class="container hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm" style="margin-bottom:-20px;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="row">
                <a class="" href="/"><img src="/assets/img/logosmall.png" style="height:30px;" /></a>
                <a style="color: white; margin-left:5px;" class="pull-right btn btn-info btn-xs" href="/pay/">Instant Pay</a>
                <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #ffc107; padding:0px; margin: 7px 0px 5px 0px">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <a class="mobilebar_elements col-xs-5" href="/login/">Login</a>
                <a class="mobilebar_elements col-xs-5" href="/signup/">Signup</a>
                <button style="padding-top:3px; margin-bottom:3px; margin-top:3px;" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed col-xs-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            <div>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tenantsandowners" class="tenantsandowners_link">Tenants & Property Owners</a></li>
            <li><a href="#payment" class="payment_link">Payment Options</a></li>
            <li><a href="#paymentpage" class="paymentpage_link">Personalised Payment Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact/">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS ([Full CSS Here](http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css)):

```
.navbar-collapse {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}
.navbar-collapse.in {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-static-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
  max-height: 340px;
}
@media (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 200px;
  }
}
.container > .navbar-header,
.container-fluid > .navbar-header,
.container > .navbar-collapse,
.container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container > .navbar-header,
  .container-fluid > .navbar-header,
  .container > .navbar-collapse,
  .container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
.navbar-static-top {
  z-index: 1000;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-static-top {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}
```

[image: Mockup]

Comment: Showing the code, or better yet, a jsfiddle of the code you're working on would go along way to help us help you.

Comment: Since I've seen your code, I can tell you it will take some restructuring of your navigation structure to achieve this effect. You'll need to break up the navigation into the top section and the dropdown section (currently there is some overlap). You'll also need to remove the background color from the overall navigation and add it separately to both sections, giving a side margin to the dropdown section.

Comment: I've added some code now @AlvinPascoe

Comment: @AndrewCarter  Added code